# How can it be shown that a matrix multiplied by it's adjoint has positive definite eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Essentially show that $ AA^\dagger $ has positive eigenvalues. It's obvious that it's hermitian, so it will have real eigenvalues, so what i've tried so far is:

$ Au = λu$

$ u^\dagger A^\dagger = λ u^\dagger$

so multiplying both sides, we get:

$  Auu^{\dagger}A^\dagger  = λ^2 uu^\dagger$

so the inner products will cancel, but I end up with a matrix equalling a positive square, which doesn't make a lot of sense. Any suggestions?

Comment: It need not be that $A$ has real eigenvalues, so we ought to have $u^{\dagger} A^{\dagger} = \bar{\lambda} u^{\dagger}$ (NB that $\lambda$ is conjugated here).

Comment: Assuming $u$ is a column vector (which it seems to be, since you've written "$Au$" in your first equation), one usualy does the product in your last expression the other way: $u^\dagger A^\dagger Au$. Note that $uu^\dagger$ is a matrix, not a number. So while $u^\dagger A^\dagger Au = \lambda^2u^\dagger u$ would be an equality of numbers, what you have is an equality of matrices.

Comment: We shouldn't gloss over the case where $A$ is singular, so that $AA^\dagger$ is only positive *semi-definite*.